# KiCad - Using a generic LQFP64 component in schematic to design an adapter

Tags: kicad

I want to make an LQFP64 adapter PCB so I can solder a microcontroller with through hole connectors. This is mainly for STM32 ARM Microcontrollers and I plan to use different versions of the same 32bit family (Cortex M0, M3, M4 etc).

However, it looks like there isn't a generic component in KiCad that I can use. I want all the pins on the component arranged sequentially, but that's not the case if I use a specific microcontroller component. The pins are arranged all over the place and it makes wiring sequentially rather difficult.

I'm hoping I don't have to create a generic component myself, it's a bit of a pain having to define and create 64 pins. Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT: Per DiBosco's suggestion, I ended up making a symbol from scratch in KiCad. Took me an hour to make it.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to do: Are you trying to interface a thru-hole micro to an SMT footprint or vice versa? Also show a picture of the KiCAD part that you think you can't use.

Comment: Are you saying that the pins aren't number 1-64 in order for a QFP footprint? They are on all QFPs on my kicad installation. Or are you saying there's no symbol where they're numbered 1-64 sequentially? If the latter , that's a pretty trivial thing to create.

Comment: [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/XVq1T) a picture of what I'm trying to make. @DiBosco - that's correct, there's no symbol where the pins are numbered sequentially. I didn't want to have to create a component, so was hoping there's something already out there.

Comment: Creating a symbol that has pins 1-32 down one side and 33-64 down another (or similar) is trivial. You've probably spent more time on here than it would take to make one. ;-)

Comment: @DiBosco - Hmm, maybe I overestimated the effort, I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the footprint you want:

https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-footprints/blob/master/Package_QFP.pretty/LQFP-64_10x10mm_P0.5mm.kicad_mod

From there, you can attach traces to your through-hole pins.

-- Edit --

If you are looking for a symbol (not a footprint), I'd use the "Connector_Generic" Library.
https://github.com/KiCad/kicad-symbols/blob/master/Connector_Generic.lib

There, you can choose Conn_02x32_*  where the '*' can be "Counter_Clockwise", "Odd_Even", "Top_Bottom", etc.

Comment: He doesn't want a footprint, he wants a symbol.

Comment: @DiBosco - Ah, I missed that part on the first read.  I've updated my answer to add the generic symbol library reference.  Thanks!

Comment: @Seth - Thanks, but I need a symbol for LQFP64 and not for connectors. In any case, I spent an hour yesterday and just made one from scratch as per DiBosco's suggestion.